# Keychain access control from the app with different names

Tags: swift, objective-c, keychain

I am using keychain in my macOS app to store jwt tokens (access and refresh)`(kSecClassGenericPassword)` and I have figure out that I can't manage existed data via the same app with another name.
I have build two equal application with different app names:

for example: **App1.app** and **App2.app**
Note: it's the same build, but with only different - app file name.

And if I created the keychain item using the first app (**App1.app**) I can't remove it from the second one.

If I double click on keychain item in Keychain Access default App I can see that there is only one app in Access Control tab (with the name **App1.app**).

Is there a way to give the access to keychain ignoring app names. Because user can change the name, or make a duplicate of the app.

Is there a solution of this behaviour?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So to solve it I set *Keychain Sharing Capability* and set (**for macOS It's very necessary!**) `kSecAttrSynchronizable` or/and `kSecUseDataProtectionKeychain`

More info here: https://medium.com/@bhojwaniravi/making-mac-oskeychain-behave-as-ios-keychain-60eedb37c173